# Angular routerLink incorrectly resolves link address

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I have a "/projects" component where i want to route to and scroll to the id="POSProject" tag element within the projects HTML file.

To do this i attempted the following:

```
<a routerLink="/projects#POSProject" routerLinkActive="active">Link text</a>
```

But when i click the text link, the URL is resolved to

```
http://localhost:4200/projects%23POSProject
```

instead of correctly resolving to

```
http://localhost:4200/projects#POSProject
```

Is there a configuration property in Angular resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place anchor tags in fragment attribute. Something like this,

```
<a [routerLink]="/projects" fragment="POSProject">Link Text!</a>
```

You can view more [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#fragment).

Comment: I didnt know what to google because i didnt know its called a fragment. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I faced the same problem in the beginning.